# How to find how big is the difference between three groups with 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, median, clinical-trials

I have three treatment groups and one score variable (dependent variable) and the data is not normal. Hence, I performed the Kruskal Wallis test to find the hypothesis. The result is there is a significant difference bwt the groups and then did pairwise Wilcoxon signed-rank to find comparisons for each pair of groups.

Now, I want to find how big is the differences of median between the groups with 95% CI. Can anyone guide me, how to do it in R apart from bootstrapping?

Comment: Please explain what "difference between the groups" might be.  Would it be a vector of differences of arithmetic means?  Differences of medians?  The range of means or medians?  Something else?  Your use of KW and Wilcoxon suggests you are *not* interested in the means, but rather in the medians, but that still leaves this question ambiguous.

Comment: @whuber: differences of medians

Comment: *Which* differences?  All of them?  Successive ones in sorted order?  Their range?  Bear in mind that the more such differences you test, the wider the CIs must become to accommodate the multiple tests.  It pays to be specific about the hypotheses you need to test.